# Making manipulation database

Tags: json, database

I am starting to learn databases, but I can't understand the concept in general. I have few questions.

1. After we make the base and connect our web application to it, how do
       we approach to a group of items and display them in web or server controles where we
           can make CSS changes?
2. For example I have base with countries in the world and their
   capital cities in two columns, and if I have to add them in a html -
               table, how do I do that, and does it not make one step for making
               the base and one more for adding them to a list so the complexity is twice bigger.
3. Why we sometimes create JSON object for database data.

Comment: It sounds like you're missing the component in the middle - a server side language. That's where you find logic that covers what you're asking above.

Comment: I don't have questions for it that is why I didn't mention it

Comment: Oh ok. So if you're using a language on the server to get records from your database, that means you're just having trouble outputting them in HTML - is that right?

Comment: Yes... Actually am using ASP.Net - C#, And I connect the server to the database, I can get the elements part of them, all of them and present them in a GridView or etc... but I don't know know how to manipulate with them.

Answer (score 0):

1. After establishing a successful connection, you will be able to bind
   data to your controls. You can do it programmatically but using
   webforms, you can easily do with `sqlDataSource`
2. For this example you can use a gridview to display that data, or you
   can use asp table and build it manually.
3. `JSON` is used to make it easy to send data between server and client.
   Otherwise you would have the client directly connect to the DB server,
   and that is not good idea.

Comment: That's okey, but if I put elements in gridview, I have limited style manipulations to make it visually good, that is why I doubt i this is the way to make them in client side.

Comment: @Merian so [add css for the gridview](http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/gridview-custom-css-style-example-in-Asp-Net-1088.aspx) ... or create your own table... what is your question?

Comment: Neither of that. https://www.airbnb.com/s/kn?guests=&ss_id=huvs4aek&source=bb&s_tag=8M6B2Llk example: How is the list of hotels made in general in this site? Sorry if I can't make my self clear.

Comment: @Merian read the source code they are using `react.js` and display the listings using divs